# Why cant I access non-static variables indirectly from non-static methods?

Tags: java, static

```
class C {
    static int b = 1;

    void f1() {
        System.out.println(C.b); // Access static variable indirectly
    }
}

class A {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        C as = new C();
        as.f1();
    }
}
```

---

```
class C {
    int a = 0;

    void f1() {
        System.out.println(C.a); // Access non static variable indirectly
    }
}

class A {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        C as = new C();
        as.f1();
    }
}
```

The 2nd program works when we write `System.out.println(**a**)` but why does it fail when we write `System.out.println(**C.a**)` as opposed to the 1st program which works when we write `System.out.println(**C.b**)`?

Comment: the first is a static field which means it belongs to the class hence it works. the second is an instance field hence you need to make an object first.

Comment: Did you intend the call to `println` to be part of `f1`?

Comment: You can do `a`, or `this.a` or `C.this.a` to access an instance variable of the current instance, but `C.a` is reserved for static access. Why? That's just how the language works.

Comment: In the second program there isn't such a thing as `C.a`.  There's a _different_ `a` for each _instance_ of `C`, not one single `a` variable, so you'll have to say _which_ `C` you mean.

Comment: The code as presented will not compile even with the `C.a` corrected.

Comment: Consider reading the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1 and §8.3 generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, we have to type of membens in the class: static and instance.

## Definition

- Instance members can be called only in instance methods as following:
  **this.a**, **a**, **C.this.a**. A instance members belongs to the object instance in the memory
- Static members can be called in both instance and static methods, because they belongs to the **Class** in the memory. If they belongs to the class, they are shared between all the instances in the memory.

### Why you cant call `System.out.println(C.a);`

1. `a` is a instance variable, thus, it must be called only in a instance
2. Java will interpret the `C.a` to call a variable `a` in a static area of the class, not a instance one